# Swift CAShapeLayer gets partially transparent at 1pt or lower

Tags: swift, line, cashapelayer

I've been trying to get a solid color when I draw a 0.5pt width line but it gets opaque when the value is 1.0 or less (see picture).

[image: 1pt solid line opaques]

This is the code (Swift 4)

```
func DrawLine(from:CGPoint, to:CGPoint) {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: from)
    path.addLine(to: to)
    let lineLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    lineLayer.path = path.cgPath
    lineLayer.lineWidth = linesWidth
    lineLayer.strokeColor = linesColor.cgColor
    lineLayer.isOpaque = false // trying to make it work line
    lineLayer.opacity = 1 // trying to make it work line
    lineLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor // trying to make it work line
    lineLayer.shadowOffset = .zero // trying to make it work line
    lineLayer.shadowOpacity = 0 // trying to make it work line
    self.layer.insertSublayer(lineLayer, at: 0)
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Opaque means no transparency. If you don't want the line to be transparent at all, set `isOpaque` to `true`.

Comment: Thx, you're right, i changed the answer

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer at https://www.raywenderlich.com/411-core-graphics-tutorial-part-1-getting-started (All because the anti-aliasing as explained in the first answer by Codo)

> If you have oddly sized straight lines, you’ll need to position them
>   at plus or minus 0.5 points to prevent anti-aliasing

So, if the lineWidth is 1pt or less I add 0.5 points or (1 / scale).

Now the line is crispy

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think when you say *opaque* you rather mean partially transparent. And I guess we're talking about macOS here, right?

How do you expect a line of less than 1 pixels looks on the screen? A pixel is the smallest unit of the screen. The entire pixel has the same color. It can't be partially red and partially white.

So macOS – as part of the *antialiasing* – blends the thin line and the background, i.e. it makes the pixels partially transparent before drawing them on the background. The effect is that the line is perceived as thinner even though it is still 1 pixel wide.

If you don't like this effect, do not draw lines of less than 1 pixel. But it's the only way a line looks thinner than 1 pixel.

BTW: Pixel size depends on the resolution. On a retina device, 1 pixel is 0.5 point, on non-retina devices it's 1 point and there are even factors in-between.

Comment: Hi, you're right about the partially transparent, and what I want is that: "the 1px solid line color" for iPhone, i'm not drawing lines of less than 1 pixel, the linesWidth is in pt, I already tried divide 1pt/scale, on an iPhone 5s scale = 2 so 0.5 means 1px, I can achieve the result with CGContext but not with CAShapeLayer, thanks for your response.

Comment: Well, I think i'm going to leave this question a couple days more before I consider this an answer, but you're right about the macOS, on an iMac (non retina) looks like the pictures before, on a MacBook (retina) looks better (just like the iPhone 7) but I still don't get the 1px solid black line, is almost black, but not black, thanks again.